# Using TDD/CODE to help this student to pass - RUBY

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to solve a TDD exercise. I managed to make the first test pass:

```
def test_grade_is_mediocre
  student = Student.new
  assert_equal 'C', student.grade
end
```

By implementing this code:

```
class Student
  attr_reader :grade


  def initialize(grade = "C")
    @grade = grade
  end

  def study
  end
end
```

But I got stuck at the second test:

```
def test_grade_can_improve
  student = Student.new
  student.study
  assert_equal "B", student.grade
  student.study
  assert_equal "A", student.grade
end
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction as to how to address the grade changes once the student studies? I have pass `grade = "C"` as an argument to get the first test to pass and I know I need to define the `study` method but am stuck in trying to figure out how to address how the student improves his grades after he studies once and then twice. Do I need to set some sort of counter?

Comment: Hi again! One way would be to look at the current grade? For example if it's a C and the student studies then it becomes a B, but if it's already a B it becomes an A. and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure that posting these questions for each exercise you have is the best way for you to learn the general ideas here so that you'll be able to do these yourself in the future? Have you got a link to the course/website where these come from?

Comment: How's it going? I appreciate that, there are no websites or links that I can refer to as far as directly addressing these exercises. Only general concepts are given to us and we have to try to implement them in the exercises given to us.

Comment: Hi! If you’re ok to drop me an email (contact details in my profile) I’ll try and give a couple of general tips that might help. Cheers.

Comment: You could change `@grade` based on its current value. So if @grade is C then set it to B. If @grade is B then set it to A. Do you know how to implement an `if` or `case` expression?

Comment: sort of, that is what im trying to grasp right now. I'm having trouble trying it figure out how to structure the if statements and what methods or terms to use to have it make sense.

Comment: I've posted an answer below but you should really try to solve this on your own. Show your attempts next time, even if they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [`if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression) expression:

```
def study
  if grade == 'C'
    @grade = 'B'
  elsif grade == 'B'
    @grade = 'A'
  end
end
```

or – a little more succinct – a [`case`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) expression:

```
def study
  case grade
  when 'C'
    @grade = 'B'
  when 'B'
    @grade = 'A'
  end
end
```

Note that I'm using the getter `grade` to *read* the value and the instance variable `@grade` to *assign* a new value.

Another approach is to use some kind of mapping, e.g. via [`tr!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-tr-21):

```
def study
  @grade.tr!('BC', 'AB')
end
```

It replaces the characters in the first argument with the corresponding characters in the second argument, i.e. `'B'` with `'A'` and `'C'` with `'B'`.

Comment: ah ok, i appreciate you going through that, I will take a look at this for a little bit and see if i can digest what you did.